# Create a column which is the mean of multiple columns in a data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, mean

So I've looked at multiple potential solutions but none seem to work.

Basically, I want to create a new column in my data frame which is the mean of multiple other columns. I want this mean to exclude NaN values but still calculate the mean even if there are NaN values in the row.

I have a data frame which looks something like this (but actually Q222-229):

```
ID   Q1   Q2   Q3   Q4   Q5
1    4    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2    5    7    8    NaN  NaN
3    7    1    2    NaN  NaN
4    2    2    3    4    1
5    1    3    NaN  NaN  NaN
```

And I want to create a column which is the mean of Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5 ie:

```
ID   Q1   Q2   Q3   Q4   Q5   avg_age
1    4    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  4
2    5    7    8    NaN  NaN  5.5
3    7    1    2    NaN  NaN  3.5
4    2    2    3    4    1    2
5    1    3    NaN  NaN  NaN  2
```

(ignore values)

However, every method I have tried returns NaN values in the avg_age column which is making me think that when ignoring the NaN values, pandas is ignoring the whole row. But I dont want this to happen, instead I want the mean returned with the NaN values ignored.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
1.
    avg_age = s.loc[: , "Q222":"Q229"]
    avg_age = avg_age.mean(axis=1)
    s = pd.concat([s, avg_age], axis=1)

2.
    s['avg_age'] = s[['Q222', 'Q223', 'Q224', 'Q225', 'Q226', 'Q227', 'Q228', 'Q229']].mean(axis=1)

3.

    avg_age = ['Q222', 'Q223', 'Q224', 'Q225', 'Q226', 'Q227', 'Q228', 'Q229']
    s.loc[:, 'avg_age'] = s[avg_age].mean(axis=1)
```

I am not sure if there is something wrong with the way I have coded the values initially so here is my code for reference:

#Changing age variable inputs

```
s['Q222'] = s['Q222'].replace(['18-24', '25-34','35-44', '45-54','55-64', '65-74', '75 or older', "Don't know"],
                              ['2','3','4','5', '6', '7', '8', np.NaN])
s['Q223'] = s['Q223'].replace(['18-24', '25-34','35-44', '45-54','55-64', '65-74', '75 or older', "Don't know"],
                              ['2','3','4','5', '6', '7', '8', np.NaN])
s['Q224'] = s['Q224'].replace(['18-24', '25-34','35-44', '45-54','55-64', '65-74', '75 or older', "Don't know"],
                              ['2','3','4','5', '6', '7', '8', np.NaN])
s['Q225'] = s['Q225'].replace(['18-24', '25-34','35-44', '45-54','55-64', '65-74', '75 or older', "Don't know"],
                              ['2','3','4','5', '6', '7', '8', np.NaN])
s['Q226'] = s['Q226'].replace(['18-24', '25-34','35-44', '45-54','55-64', '65-74', '75 or older', "Don't know"],
                              ['2','3','4','5', '6', '7', '8', np.NaN])
s['Q227'] = s['Q227'].replace(['18-24', '25-34','35-44', '45-54','55-64', '65-74', '75 or older', "Don't know"],
                              ['2','3','4','5', '6', '7', '8', np.NaN])
s['Q228'] = s['Q228'].replace(['18-24', '25-34','35-44', '45-54','55-64', '65-74', '75 or older', "Don't know"],
                              ['2','3','4','5', '6', '7', '8', np.NaN])
s['Q229'] = s['Q229'].replace(['18-24', '25-34','35-44', '45-54','55-64', '65-74', '75 or older', "Don't know"],
                              ['2','3','4','5', '6', '7', '8', np.NaN])

s['Q222'] = s['Q222'].replace(['0-4', '05-11', '12-15', '16-17'], '1')
s['Q223'] = s['Q223'].replace(['0-4', '05-11', '12-15', '16-17'], '1')
s['Q224'] = s['Q224'].replace(['0-4', '05-11', '12-15', '16-17'], '1')
s['Q225'] = s['Q225'].replace(['0-4', '05-11', '12-15', '16-17'], '1')
s['Q226'] = s['Q226'].replace(['0-4', '05-11', '12-15', '16-17'], '1')
s['Q227'] = s['Q227'].replace(['0-4', '05-11', '12-15', '16-17'], '1')
s['Q228'] = s['Q228'].replace(['0-4', '05-11', '12-15', '16-17'], '1')
s['Q229'] = s['Q229'].replace(['0-4', '05-11', '12-15', '16-17'], '1')
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who is able to help!

Comment: You can use: `df['avg_age'] = df.iloc[:,1:].mean(axis=1)`, since you don't want the mean of the first column (I.E> all columns BUT first).

Comment: How is 5.5 the mean of 5, 7 and 8?

Comment: ^^^ some of your means do not add up (or I should say "mean up").

Comment: Thank you David. As I said in the post ignore the values as they are just arbitrary for the purpose of the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior of `DataFrame.mean()` should do what you want.

Here's an example showing taking a mean over a subset of the columns and placing it in a newly created column:

```
In[19]: tmp
Out[19]: 
   a  b    c
0  1  2  5.0
1  2  3  6.0
2  3  4  NaN

In[24]: tmp['mean'] = tmp[['b', 'c']].mean(axis=1)

In[25]: tmp
Out[25]: 
   a  b    c  mean
0  1  2  5.0   3.5
1  2  3  6.0   4.5
2  3  4  NaN   4.0
```

As for what's going wrong in your code:

> ```
> s['Q222'] = s['Q222'].replace(['18-24', '25-34','35-44', '45-54','55-64', '65-74', '75 or older', "Don't know"],
>                          ['2','3','4','5', '6', '7', '8', np.NaN])
> ```

You don't have numerical values (i.e 2, 3, 4) in your data frame, you have strings ('2', '3', and '4'). The `DataFrame.mean()` function is treating these strings as NaN, so you are getting NaN as the result for all your mean calculations.

Try filling your frame with numbers, like so:

```
 s['Q222'] = s['Q222'].replace(['18-24', '25-34','35-44', '45-54','55-64', '65-74', '75 or older', "Don't know"],
                          [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, np.NaN])
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadnt realised that my replace function was making the numbers into a string (rookie move) so thank you for spotting that!

Answer (score 0):

`skipna=True`

Can get it with a `list comprehension` to get the columns to average, and `mean()` with:

```
df['ave_age'] = df[[col for col in df.columns if 'Q' in col]].mean(axis = 1,skipna = True)
```